# Static response WORKS! While Asynchronous doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-directive

I'm creating an angular directive for realtime chart displaying here is the code  which returns everything including `link:function() { }` inside directive.

Here is the code for static directive *which works perfectly*

```
angular.module('app').directive("flotChartRealtime", [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            link: function(scope, ele) {
                var realTimedata,
                    realTimedata2,
                    totalPoints,
                    getSeriesObj,
                    getRandomData,
                    getRandomData2,
                    updateInterval,
                    plot,
                    update;
                return realTimedata = [],
                    realTimedata2 = [],
                    totalPoints = 100,
                    getSeriesObj = function() {
                        return [
                            {
                                data: getRandomData(),
                                lines: {
                                    show: true,
                                    lineWidth: 1,
                                    fill: true,
                                    fillColor: {
                                        colors: [
                                            {
                                                opacity: 0
                                            }, {
                                                opacity: 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    steps: false
                                },
                                shadowSize: 0
                            }, {
                                data: getRandomData2(),
                                lines: {
                                    lineWidth: 0,
                                    fill: true,
                                    fillColor: {
                                        colors: [
                                            {
                                                opacity: .5
                                            }, {
                                                opacity: 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    steps: false
                                },
                                shadowSize: 0
                            }
                        ];
                    },
                    getRandomData = function() {
                        if (realTimedata.length > 0)
                            realTimedata = realTimedata.slice(1);

                        // Do a random walk
                        //console.log(realTimedata);
                        while (realTimedata.length < totalPoints) {

                            var prev = realTimedata.length > 0 ? realTimedata[realTimedata.length - 1] : 50,
                                y = prev + Math.random() * 10 - 5;

                            if (y < 0) {
                                y = 0;
                            } else if (y > 100) {
                                y = 100;
                            }
                            realTimedata.push(y);
                        }

                        // Zip the generated y values with the x values

                        var res = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < realTimedata.length; ++i) {
                            res.push([i, realTimedata[i]]);
                        }

                        return res;
                    },
                    getRandomData2 = function() {
                        if (realTimedata2.length > 0)
                            realTimedata2 = realTimedata2.slice(1);

                        // Do a random walk

                        while (realTimedata2.length < totalPoints) {

                            var prev = realTimedata2.length > 0 ? realTimedata[realTimedata2.length] : 50,
                                y = prev - 25;

                            if (y < 0) {
                                y = 0;
                            } else if (y > 100) {
                                y = 100;
                            }
                            realTimedata2.push(y);
                        }


                        var res = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < realTimedata2.length; ++i) {
                            res.push([i, realTimedata2[i]]);
                        }

                        return res;
                    },

                    // Set up the control widget
                    updateInterval = 500,
                    plot = $.plot(ele[0], getSeriesObj(), {
                        yaxis: {
                            color: '#f3f3f3',
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        },
                        xaxis: {
                            color: '#f3f3f3',
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100,
                            tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        },
                        grid: {
                            hoverable: true,
                            clickable: false,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            aboveData: false
                        },
                        colors: ['#eee', scope.settings.color.themeprimary],
                    }),
                    update = function() {
                        plot.setData(getSeriesObj()); // getting .data filled here perfectly
                        plot.draw();
                        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
                    },
                    update();
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

---

My code with HTTP request *which doesn't work*

```
 getSeriesObj = function () {
     return [{
         data: getRandomData(function(res) {
             console.log(res) // getting array result here from http call but not returning to data:
             return res; 
         }),
         lines: {
             show: true,
             lineWidth: 1,
             fill: true,
             fillColor: {
                 colors: [{
                     opacity: 0
                 }, {
                     opacity: 1
                 }]
             },
             steps: false
         },
         shadowSize: 0
     }, {
         data: getRandomData2(function (res) {
             return res;
         }),
         lines: {
             lineWidth: 0,
             fill: true,
             fillColor: {
                 colors: [{
                     opacity: .5
                 }, {
                     opacity: 1
                 }]
             },
             steps: false
         },
         shadowSize: 0
     }];
 },
 getRandomData = function (callback) {
     var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
     var url = $rootScope.apiPath + 'Elasticsearch/countget?token=' + authToken;
     var res = [];
     $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
         realTimedata = result.data;
         if (realTimedata.length > 0)
         //result = [10,22,33,11,32,88,77,66,21,90,92,98,99.9,88.8,76,66,56,88];
         for (var i = 0; i < realTimedata.length; ++i) {
             var y = realTimedata[i] + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
             if (y < 0) {
                 y = 0;
             } else if (y > 100) {
                 y = 100;
             }
             res.push([i, y]);
         }
         callback(res);
     });
 },
```

**Problem**:

When i try following code:

```
update = function () {
    //console.log(getSeriesObj());
    plot.setData(getSeriesObj()); // .data property gets undefined
    plot.draw();
    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
}
```

function `getSeriesObj()` return array of object which return `data` property to `undefined` what can be the reason?

how can i resolve this?

*Note:* This is far different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: is `getRandomData2` same as `getRandomData ` ? because if so then `getRandomData2` might return nothing because of the async task so `data` is undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `data: getRandomData2(function (res) {return res;})` this execute `getRandomData2`,  what does return `getRandomData2` ? `undefined` . Your issue is the same as defined in the post I linked. You are not able to return the response from the async call

Comment: @Hacketo Both are same right now just!

Comment: @Hacketo I'm getting result where i call `data: getRandomData2(function (res) {return res;})` where `res` is an array but it's not getting populated inside `update()` at the bottom.

Comment: `res` is an array, but what is `data` then ? `undefined`,  the problem you asked about

Comment: @Hacketo `res = [[1,2],[2,3].......]`  i get this response inside `res`! and this `res` is returned to `data` property! but i get undefined in `update()`

Comment: so what is the problem ? `res` is not returned to `data`, `data` is undefined, this is not a function

Comment: If you want to see it , just call `getRandomData2(function (res) {return res;})` in js console, you will see that it return nothing, so assigning the return of that function to `data` is your problem

Comment: @Hacketo I did it, it returns me the result in `res`!

Comment: the function call itself return nothing so you assign nothing to `data`, as opposite of the first `data` value where you assign a function to `data`. If you can't understand that, the post linked is the solution

Comment: BTW after your last edit, `data: getRandomData(res) { return res; }` is not valid javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89253/discussion-between-dhaval-marthak-and-hacketo).

Comment: I guess you are not returning anything in the Async call... that might be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do this

```
data: getRandomData(function(res) {
    return res; 
});
```

You assign the rValue of `getRandomData` to `data`.

As stated in your post, `getRandomData` now has no `return` statement, so return `undefined`.

The main problem here is that you expect that `plot.setData(getSeriesObj());` work `synchronously`

Steps

1. get the data to fill `plot`
2. set the data to the `plot`
3. draw it
4. update the values again

Now as the http request work async you cannot expect to retrieve a value from `getSeriesObj()`. You have to think that `getSeriesObj` work now async so you can only work with callback that will be fired when the resource is ready to be used

so the update method become

```
update = function () {
    var updateTime = +new Date;
    getSeriesObj(function(res){ // execute that stuff when ready
        plot.setData(res);
        plot.draw();
        setTimeout(update, Math.max(10, updateInterval - (+new Date - updateTime)) );
    });
}
```

and `getSeriesObj`

```
getSeriesObj = function (callback) {
    getRandomData(function(res) {
        getRandomData2(function(res2){
            var data = [{
                data: res,
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0
                        }, {
                            opacity: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    steps: false
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            }, {
                data: res2,
                lines: {
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: .5
                        }, {
                            opacity: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    steps: false
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            }];
            callback(data); // now the ressource obj is now ready to be used
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: since callback is not in the scope where you've written, it throws error of `callback is not defined`!

Comment: callback need to be defined as parameter of  `getSeriesObj` so in the same scope as the `callback(data)` call

Comment: Many thanks Hacketo! It's working perfectly! Cheers!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I updated the `update` function to keep a rate of drawing each 500 ms, I forgot that part.